# How to convert class component table to functional component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm a beginner of React Native. I learned React with functional components. I want to use this example table for my project but, I don't know how to deal with class components. I googled and tried to convert class component to functional components but I can't .. I have been working at this for hours now.

If anyone would be so kind as to help I would so appreciate it!!

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, View, Text, TouchableOpacity, Alert} from 'react-native';
import {
  Table,
  TableWrapper,
  Col,
  Cols,
  Cell,
} from 'react-native-table-component';

export default class ExampleFive extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const elementButton = value => (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this._alertIndex(value)}>
        <View style={styles.btn}>
          <Text style={styles.btnText}>공강</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );

    this.state = {
      tableTitle: [
        '1교시',
        '2교시',
        '3교시',
        '4교시',
        '5교시',
        '6교시',
        '7교시',
        '8교시',
        '9교시',
      ],
      tableData: [
        [
          'Mon',
          elementButton('Mon1'),
          elementButton('Mon2'),
          elementButton('Mon3'),
          elementButton('Mon4'),
          elementButton('Mon5'),
          elementButton('Mon6'),
          elementButton('Mon7'),
          elementButton('Mon8'),
          elementButton('Mon9'),
        ],
        [
          'Tue',
          elementButton('Tue1'),
          elementButton('Tue2'),
          elementButton('Tue3'),
          elementButton('Tue4'),
          elementButton('Tue5'),
          elementButton('Tue6'),
          elementButton('Tue7'),
          elementButton('Tue8'),
          elementButton('Tue9'),
        ],
        [
          'Wed',
          elementButton('Wed1'),
          elementButton('Wed2'),
          elementButton('Wed3'),
          elementButton('Wed4'),
          elementButton('Wed5'),
          elementButton('Wed6'),
          elementButton('Wed7'),
          elementButton('Wed8'),
          elementButton('Wed9'),
        ],
        [
          'Thus',
          elementButton('Thus1'),
          elementButton('Thus2'),
          elementButton('Thus3'),
          elementButton('Thus4'),
          elementButton('Thus5'),
          elementButton('Thus6'),
          elementButton('Thus7'),
          elementButton('Thus8'),
          elementButton('Thus9'),
        ],
        [
          'Fri',
          elementButton('Fri1'),
          elementButton('Fri2'),
          elementButton('Fri3'),
          elementButton('Fri4'),
          elementButton('Fri5'),
          elementButton('Fri6'),
          elementButton('Fri7'),
          elementButton('Fri8'),
          elementButton('Fri9'),
        ],
      ],
    };
  }

  _alertIndex(value) {
    Alert.alert(`This is column ${value}`);
  }

  render() {
    const state = this.state;
    return (
      <View style={styles.container2}>
        <Text>MY SCHEDULE</Text>
        <Table style={{flexDirection: 'row'}} borderStyle={{borderWidth: 1}}>
          {/* Left Wrapper */}
          <TableWrapper style={{width: 80}}>
            <Cell data="" style={styles.singleHead} />
            <TableWrapper style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
              <Col
                data={state.tableTitle}
                style={styles.title}
                heightArr={[30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30]}
                textStyle={styles.titleText}></Col>
            </TableWrapper>
          </TableWrapper>

          {/* Right Wrapper */}
          <TableWrapper style={{flex: 1}}>
            <Cols
              data={state.tableData}
              heightArr={[40, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30]}
              textStyle={styles.text}
            />
          </TableWrapper>
        </Table>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container2: {flex: 1, padding: 16, paddingTop: 30, backgroundColor: '#fff'},
  singleHead: {width: 80, height: 40, backgroundColor: '#c8e1ff'},
  head: {flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#c8e1ff'},
  title: {flex: 2, backgroundColor: '#f6f8fa'},
  titleText: {marginRight: 6, textAlign: 'right'},
  text: {textAlign: 'center'},
  btn: {
    width: 40,
    height: 18,
    marginLeft: 8,
    backgroundColor: '#c8e1ff',
    borderRadius: 2,
  },
  btnText: {textAlign: 'center'},
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This component, translated into a functional component, will become:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, View, Text, TouchableOpacity, Alert} from 'react-native';
import {
  Table,
  TableWrapper,
  Col,
  Cols,
  Cell,
} from 'react-native-table-component';

const ExampleFive = (props) => {
  const elementButton = value => (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this._alertIndex(value)}>
        <View style={styles.btn}>
          <Text style={styles.btnText}>공강</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
  );

  let myState = { /*all the content of this.state*/ };

  const [state, setState] = useState(myState);
  
  const _alertIndex(value) {
    Alert.alert(`This is column ${value}`);
  }

    return (
      <View style={styles.container2}>
        <Text>MY SCHEDULE</Text>
        <Table style={{flexDirection: 'row'}} borderStyle={{borderWidth: 1}}>
          {/* Left Wrapper */}
          <TableWrapper style={{width: 80}}>
            <Cell data="" style={styles.singleHead} />
            <TableWrapper style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
              <Col
                data={state.tableTitle}
                style={styles.title}
                heightArr={[30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30]}
                textStyle={styles.titleText}></Col>
            </TableWrapper>
          </TableWrapper>

          {/* Right Wrapper */}
          <TableWrapper style={{flex: 1}}>
            <Cols
              data={state.tableData}
              heightArr={[40, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30]}
              textStyle={styles.text}
            />
          </TableWrapper>
        </Table>
      </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container2: {flex: 1, padding: 16, paddingTop: 30, backgroundColor: '#fff'},
  singleHead: {width: 80, height: 40, backgroundColor: '#c8e1ff'},
  head: {flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#c8e1ff'},
  title: {flex: 2, backgroundColor: '#f6f8fa'},
  titleText: {marginRight: 6, textAlign: 'right'},
  text: {textAlign: 'center'},
  btn: {
    width: 40,
    height: 18,
    marginLeft: 8,
    backgroundColor: '#c8e1ff',
    borderRadius: 2,
  },
  btnText: {textAlign: 'center'},
});

export default ExampleFive;
```

Note:

- removed `constructor`;
- in functional component, state should be managed by using hook `useState`;
- removed `render`.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is replace the class declaration (with constructor/super(props), etc.), with function declaration, put `tableTitle` and `tableData` inside useState instead of the `this.state =`  statement, and return the render() return directly in your new functional component